# Close GUI but continue script in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to have a gui close but leave the script running. This is because I want to do other actions if the user chooses to escape the GUI by either hitting `esc` or simply clicking the 'X' in the upper right. I don't understand how I would leave the script running but close the gui. GUI close doesn't seem to do anything when clicking `esc` or the X. I've scanned through the [GUI](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#GuiClose) docs and cannot figure it out. They always run exitapp, but I'm not ready to exitapp, I need to do other things.

```
Gui, Add, Text, ,To cancel, press ESCAPE or close this window.

Gui, Show, w320 h80, Downloads

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
; Continue on to do other things here!!!!
WinActivate ahk_exe notepad++.exe
; do things...
exitapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like what I wanted to do, too. It was a lot of slogging and piecemealing but I think what you are looking for is `Gui, Cancel` Take a look at the code below and see if that doesn't solve your problem.

It doesn't use `ExitApp` and it doesn't destroy the window if you want to pop it up later. You'll have to figure how to place the rest of your code, but I believe this is what you are asking.

```
;Set the GUI window
Gui, Add, Text,, Hit Escape to Clear window when it is active

#F9:: ;show the window with WindowsKey-F9 
Gui, Show, 
return

;set the escape key to clear GUI window
GuiEscape: ; Note: single colon here, not double
Gui, Cancel
Return
```

It's a little trickier if you have multiple GUI windows. You must name each:

```
;Set the two GUI windows. In example, First is labeled as FirstGUI and second as SecondGUI. Notice how you separate with single colon.
Gui, FirstGUI:Add, Text,, Hit Escape to Clear FirstGUI window when it is active
Gui, SecondGUI:Add, Text,, Hit Escape to Clear SecondGUI window when it is active

#F9:: ;show the two windows ("xCenter y700" is used to prevent the windows from stacking.)
Gui, FirstGUI:Show, xCenter y700, Window Title of First GUI
Gui, SecondGUI:Show, xCenter y900, Window Title of Second GUI
return

;set the escape key to clear for each Gui independently. 

FirstGUIGuiEscape: ; Note that you must add the Gui Name (FirstGUI) to the beginning of the "GuiEscape:" command and also name it in the following:
Gui, FirstGUI:Cancel
Return

SecondGUIGuiEscape: ; And here you must add SecondGUI as noted above.
Gui, SecondGUI:Cancel
Return
```

Answering a little late but hope this works for you or someone else!

Answer (score 1):

They assume in the documentation that by clicking x, you'd want the script to close.
So they show `ExitApp` as an example.

If you don't want to do that though, of course no need to do it.
I think what you're after is [destroying](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Destroy) the gui:

```
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
    Gui, Destroy
return
```